# How to use reduce with list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

What is wrong with the following?:

```
lss = reduce(list.extend, [[1],[2]], [])
```

causes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#230>", line 1, in <module>
    lss = reduce(list.extend, [[1],[2]], [])
TypeError: descriptor 'extend' requires a 'list' object but received a 'NoneType'
```

I'm not sure where the `NoneType` is coming from.

Comment: What is your desired result?/ What list are you trying to extend?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
lss = reduce(lambda acc, ele : acc + ele, [[1],[2]], [])

lss
> [1, 2]
```

The problem is that [`extend()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) returns `None` (that's where the `NoneType` is coming from), and that won't work with what you want to do - the function passed to [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce) *must* return a value: the accumulated result so far.

Comment: I realise I can do that. I would still like to know what is wrong with using the list.extend method. It seems like it should work. - your edit answered this.

Comment: @cammil as I mentioned above: `extend()` will _always_ return `None`; for `reduce()` to work the function that gets executed _has to_ return a value: the accumulated result so far.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering *why* `list.extend()` returns `None`: it's because in Python, functions that mutate a data structure always return `None`, because Python is abiding by Command/Query Separation.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation

Answer (score 8):

I think it worth noting that:

```
sum([[1],[2]], [])
```

Will also work, and I'm pretty sure will be faster then passing a lambda to reduce.

I was curious as to the speed of different methods, so I did some testing:

```
reduce(lambda a,b:a+b, x, [])               3644.38161492
reduce(list.__add__, x, [])                 3609.44079709
sum(x,[])                                   3526.84987307
y = [];for z in x: y.extend(z)               143.370306969
y = [];map(y.extend,x)                        71.7020270824
y = [None]*400;del y[:];map(y.extend,x)       66.2245891094
list(itertools.chain(*x))                    102.285979986
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))        96.6231369972
[a for b in x for a in b]                    203.764872074
```

And on PyPy (Because, why not)

```
reduce(lambda a,b:a+b, x, [])               4797.5895648
reduce(list.__add__, x, [])                 4794.01214004
sum(x,[])                                   4748.02929902
y = [];for z in x: y.extend(z)                56.9253079891
y = [];map(y.extend,x)                        73.8642170429
y = [None]*400;del y[:];map(y.extend,x)      152.157783031
list(itertools.chain(*x))                    633.854824066
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))       629.917827129
[a for b in x for a in b]                     89.6922459602

x = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7],[5,6,7,8],[6,7,8,9],[7,8,9,10],[8,9,10,11]]*100
```

Conclusions:

1. Using a lambda in your reduce is slow
2. The specialized `sum` function is faster then reduce
3. Adding lists is slow.
4. Python loop overhead is significant.

Comment: If you set x = x*100 you can start to see the real speed differences between the algorithms.

Comment: Unfortunately, the [two ways of joining a list of lists that are usually recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) are lacking from this benchmark: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))` and `[b for a in x for b in a]`.  The first one is probably the fastest option.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, added them. However, my results have them both being slower than some of the existing options.

Comment: On two machines I tested, `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))` is consistently faster than `list(itertools.chain(*x))`, and by quite a margin so for bigger lists that don't have the artificially high cache locality of your example list (caused by `* 100`, which reuses the same lists hundred times).  It is indeed slower than `y = []; map(y.extend, x)`, though.  Interesting post!

Comment: @SvenMarnach, I went ahead and reran all the tests, my results now fit your experiences.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: I like the new option you added – I certainly wouldn't have expected this result.  I would only use it if I really need the extra bit of performance, but it is an interesting option to be aware of – the Python list analogue of `std::vector::reserve()`.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Óscar López, `list.extend` returns `None` and thus cannot be used with `reduce`. Alternatively to the suggested use of the `lambda` function, you could also use `list.__add__` with `reduce`:

```
>>> reduce(list.__add__, [[1],[2]], [])
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until
>   it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the
>   iterables are exhausted. Used for treating consecutive sequences as a
>   single sequence. Equivalent to:

```
def chain(*iterables):
    # chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F
    for it in iterables:
        for element in it:
            yield element
```